# Error in importing environment OpenAI Gym/can not make environment 'SpaceInvaders-v0' by gym library

Tags: python, importerror, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

i'm trying to use SpaceInvaders enviroment from gym library but I get Error!

my code is:

```
import gym
import gym[atari]
env = gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v0')
```

when I try to run that i'm getting this Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 env = gym.make("SpaceInvaders-v0")
```

.
.
.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'NotRequired' from 'typing_extensions' (C:\Users\sun1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

I am uninstall&install gym and gym[atari] but it had no effect

thank you for your attention

Comment: What version of typing_extensions is installed? NotRequired only appears to be present in versions 4.0.0 and greater.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was a problem in importing the **gym** library, which I was able to solve by using the Conda environment and by reinstalling the **gym** and **gym[Atari]** packages on the Conda environment with Python 3.7.
No specific problem was found in gym library that required manual installation of Atari environments.